# Calculating cumsum of mortality before a specific date in R

Tags: r, date, group-by, cumsum

I need help writing either a for loop or dply code for two things:

1. Calculating the cumsum of mortality (%), grouped on Unit, in a defined period (7 days) before a treatment.
2. Make a vector that counts the day post last treatment until next treatment.

The data sett looks like this:

```r
Unit    Date    Prcent_daily.mortality  Date.treatment
A   20.07.2020  0.2 NA
A   21.07.2020  0   NA
A   22.07.2020  0.4 NA
A   23.07.2020  0.3 NA
A   24.07.2020  0.6 NA
A   25.07.2020  0.05    NA
A   26.07.2020  0   NA
A   27.07.2020  0   NA
A   28.07.2020  0.01    28.07.2020
A   29.07.2020  0.1 NA
A   30.07.2020  0.2 NA
A   31.07.2020  0   NA
A   01.08.2020  0.2 NA
A   02.08.2020  0.3 NA
A   03.08.2020  0.3 NA
A   04.08.2020  0.05    NA
A   05.08.2020  0   NA
A   06.08.2020  0   NA
A   07.08.2020  0.01    05.08.2020
A   08.08.2020  0.1 NA
A   09.08.2020  0.2 NA
```

And I want to achieve this:

```r
Unit    Date    Prcent_daily.mortality  Date.treatment  akkum.7dbt  days.post.treatment
A   20.07.2020  0.2 NA  NA  NA
A   21.07.2020  0   NA  1.35    NA
A   22.07.2020  0.4 NA  1.35    NA
A   23.07.2020  0.3 NA  1.35    NA
A   24.07.2020  0.6 NA  1.35    NA
A   25.07.2020  0.05    NA  1.35    NA
A   26.07.2020  0   NA  1.35    NA
A   27.07.2020  0   NA  1.35    NA
A   28.07.2020  0.01    28.07.2020  1.35    0
A   29.07.2020  0.1 NA  NA  1
A   30.07.2020  0.2 NA  NA  2
A   31.07.2020  0   NA  0.85    3
A   01.08.2020  0.2 NA  0.85    4
A   02.08.2020  0.3 NA  0.85    5
A   03.08.2020  0.3 NA  0.85    6
A   04.08.2020  0.05    NA  0.85    7
A   05.08.2020  0   NA  0.85    8
A   06.08.2020  0   NA  0.85    9
A   07.08.2020  0.01    05.08.2020  0.85    0
A   08.08.2020  0.1 NA  NA  1
A   09.08.2020  0.2 NA  NA  2
```

Thanks for all help form a self learned R amateur.

Comment: Can you add your data using `dput`, see here for  how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution which combines `base R` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Create empty col for index
i1 <- which(!is.na(df$Date.treatment))
i2 <- i1-7
i1 <- i1-1
i3 <- 1:length(i1)
#Create index for second var
j1 <- which(!is.na(df$Date.treatment))
j2 <- 1:length(j1)
# i3 <- i1+1
df$Var <- NA
df$Var[i1]<-i3
df$Var[i2]<-i3
df$Var[1] <- 0
df$Var <- ifelse(!is.na(df$Date.treatment),0,df$Var)
#Fill
df %>% fill(Var) -> df1
#Create aggregations
df1 %>% filter(Var!=0) %>% group_by(Var) %>% mutate(Cum=cumsum(Prcent_daily.mortality)) %>%
  filter(Cum==max(Cum)) %>% filter(!duplicated(Cum)) %>% ungroup() %>% select(c(Unit,Cum)) -> Ag1
#Create another var
df$Var2 <- NA
df$Var2[j1] <- j2
df$Var2[1] <- 0
#Fill
df %>% fill(Var2) -> df2
#Create cums and days
df2 %>% group_by(Unit,Var2) %>% mutate(Day=(1:n())-1) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-c(Var2))  -> df3
#Empty var for cums
df3$Cum <- NA
df3$Cum[i1+1] <- Ag1$Cum
#Fill 2
df3 %>% fill(Cum,.direction = 'up') -> df4
#Some adjusts
df4$Day[1:i1[1]]<-NA
df4$Cum[1] <- NA
df4$Cum <- ifelse((df4$Day==1 | df4$Day==2) & !is.na(df4$Day),NA,df4$Cum)
```

This will produce:

```
   Unit       Date Prcent_daily.mortality Date.treatment Var Day  Cum
1     A 20.07.2020                   0.20           <NA>   0  NA   NA
2     A 21.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>   1  NA 1.35
3     A 22.07.2020                   0.40           <NA>  NA  NA 1.35
4     A 23.07.2020                   0.30           <NA>  NA  NA 1.35
5     A 24.07.2020                   0.60           <NA>  NA  NA 1.35
6     A 25.07.2020                   0.05           <NA>  NA  NA 1.35
7     A 26.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>  NA  NA 1.35
8     A 27.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>   1  NA 1.35
9     A 28.07.2020                   0.01     28.07.2020   0   0 1.35
10    A 29.07.2020                   0.10           <NA>  NA   1   NA
11    A 30.07.2020                   0.20           <NA>  NA   2   NA
12    A 31.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>   2   3 0.85
13    A 01.08.2020                   0.20           <NA>  NA   4 0.85
14    A 02.08.2020                   0.30           <NA>  NA   5 0.85
15    A 03.08.2020                   0.30           <NA>  NA   6 0.85
16    A 04.08.2020                   0.05           <NA>  NA   7 0.85
17    A 05.08.2020                   0.00           <NA>  NA   8 0.85
18    A 06.08.2020                   0.00           <NA>   2   9 0.85
19    A 07.08.2020                   0.01     05.08.2020   0   0 0.85
20    A 08.08.2020                   0.10           <NA>  NA   1   NA
21    A 09.08.2020                   0.20           <NA>  NA   2   NA
```

**Update:** Working on `df4` you can get the cumsum of `Prcent_daily.mortality` with next code:

```
#You can work with df4 to complete the rest of aggregations
#First create an dpuplicate var
df4$DateD <- df4$Date.treatment
#Now fill and mutate
df4 %>% fill(DateD) -> df4
#Create index for replacement
k <- df4$Date.treatment==df4$DateD & !is.na(df4$Date.treatment)
#Assign a value for aggregations not considered
df4$DateD[k]<-'NULL'
#Cumsum
df4 %>% group_by(DateD) %>% mutate(CumAfter=cumsum(Prcent_daily.mortality)) -> df4
#Now remove redundant values in the cum and drop the reference var
df4 %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(CumAfter=ifelse(is.na(DateD) | DateD=='NULL',NA,CumAfter)) %>%
  select(-DateD) -> df4
```

The output will be next:

```
   Unit       Date Prcent_daily.mortality Date.treatment Var Day  Cum CumAfter
1     A 20.07.2020                   0.20           <NA>   0  NA   NA       NA
2     A 21.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>   1  NA 1.35       NA
3     A 22.07.2020                   0.40           <NA>  NA  NA 1.35       NA
4     A 23.07.2020                   0.30           <NA>  NA  NA 1.35       NA
5     A 24.07.2020                   0.60           <NA>  NA  NA 1.35       NA
6     A 25.07.2020                   0.05           <NA>  NA  NA 1.35       NA
7     A 26.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>  NA  NA 1.35       NA
8     A 27.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>   1  NA 1.35       NA
9     A 28.07.2020                   0.01     28.07.2020   0   0 1.35       NA
10    A 29.07.2020                   0.10           <NA>  NA   1   NA     0.10
11    A 30.07.2020                   0.20           <NA>  NA   2   NA     0.30
12    A 31.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>   2   3 0.85     0.30
13    A 01.08.2020                   0.20           <NA>  NA   4 0.85     0.50
14    A 02.08.2020                   0.30           <NA>  NA   5 0.85     0.80
15    A 03.08.2020                   0.30           <NA>  NA   6 0.85     1.10
16    A 04.08.2020                   0.05           <NA>  NA   7 0.85     1.15
17    A 05.08.2020                   0.00           <NA>  NA   8 0.85     1.15
18    A 06.08.2020                   0.00           <NA>   2   9 0.85     1.15
19    A 07.08.2020                   0.01     05.08.2020   0   0 0.85       NA
20    A 08.08.2020                   0.10           <NA>  NA   1   NA     0.10
21    A 09.08.2020                   0.20           <NA>  NA   2   NA     0.30
```

Comment: This is really helpfull! I'll run this code on my data set and see if it works. Regards

Comment: @Molu Yeah check please, also the data you provided was short. Just consider being careful with names :)

Comment: Hi Duck, sorry about not responding earlier, but my wife gave birth to our 2.nd child 4 days ago. Your script runs perfectly in my data set and I'm very grateful for your help. I have an additional Q and that is if you cloud help me calculating the cumsum of morts post treatment that stops at the next treatment. I'm truly grateful for your support! And sorry about not giving you more data, because it contains sensitive information. M

Comment: @Molu Oh congrats on your child. Let me check how to compute what you want! Just text me on this question later so that I can recall about it :)

Comment: Great! I will :)

Comment: @Molu Fantastic! Just text me and I will test how to compute what you want. Also, if you feel comfortable with this answer you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of the answer!

Comment: Hi Duck. Now I'm back on work and wonder if you could calculate the cumsum of morts post each treatment? Regards M

Comment: @Molu Hi dear. For sure. Could you just please give me a little example as I am confused of what to compute?

Comment: @Molu For example in the above output what you want now is the sum of `Prcent_daily.mortality` from row 10 to row 18? An continue so on for the rest of treatments?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for being unclear. Yes I want to calculate the cumulative sum of Prcent_daily.mortality from row 10 to 18 and then from row 20 to 21. I want all registrations before row 10 to have NA's registered as there have been no treatment before that date.

Comment: @Molu Hi dear. I have updated the code to do what you want. I hope this can help. And if you consider this answer was helpful for your issue you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot, I will run the code during the weekend. I clicked on the scoring of usefulness of the answer and hope this was what you meant :)

Comment: @Molu Actually the answer has not been accepted by you. Could you see in the left side of this answer (left side of the sentence starting with 'Try') there is a tick, you should click on that in order to accept. Could you please check ? :)

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution. Although you are looking for a `dplyr` solution, I just want to share.

The idea is creating flags indicating 7 (or 8?) days before the treatment and the days after a treatment.

```r
library(data.table)
odt <- fread('Unit    Date    Prcent_daily.mortality  Date.treatment
A   20.07.2020  0.2 NA
A   21.07.2020  0   NA
A   22.07.2020  0.4 NA
A   23.07.2020  0.3 NA
A   24.07.2020  0.6 NA
A   25.07.2020  0.05    NA
A   26.07.2020  0   NA
A   27.07.2020  0   NA
A   28.07.2020  0.01    28.07.2020
A   29.07.2020  0.1 NA
A   30.07.2020  0.2 NA
A   31.07.2020  0   NA
A   01.08.2020  0.2 NA
A   02.08.2020  0.3 NA
A   03.08.2020  0.3 NA
A   04.08.2020  0.05    NA
A   05.08.2020  0   NA
A   06.08.2020  0   NA
A   07.08.2020  0.01    05.08.2020
A   08.08.2020  0.1 NA
A   09.08.2020  0.2 NA')

#create group flags
odt[,postgrp:=cumsum(!is.na(Date.treatment)),by=.(Unit)]
odt[,pregrp:= c(if (postgrp-1 < 0) 0 else postgrp-1,rep(postgrp,.N-1)),by=.(Unit,postgrp)]

treat_date <- odt[,.I[!is.na(Date.treatment)]]
pre7_date <- unlist(Map(seq,treat_date-7,treat_date))
odt[!pre7_date,pregrp:=NA][]
#>     Unit       Date Prcent_daily.mortality Date.treatment postgrp pregrp
#>  1:    A 20.07.2020                   0.20           <NA>       0     NA
#>  2:    A 21.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>       0      0
#>  3:    A 22.07.2020                   0.40           <NA>       0      0
#>  4:    A 23.07.2020                   0.30           <NA>       0      0
#>  5:    A 24.07.2020                   0.60           <NA>       0      0
#>  6:    A 25.07.2020                   0.05           <NA>       0      0
#>  7:    A 26.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>       0      0
#>  8:    A 27.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>       0      0
#>  9:    A 28.07.2020                   0.01     28.07.2020       1      0
#> 10:    A 29.07.2020                   0.10           <NA>       1     NA
#> 11:    A 30.07.2020                   0.20           <NA>       1     NA
#> 12:    A 31.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>       1      1
#> 13:    A 01.08.2020                   0.20           <NA>       1      1
#> 14:    A 02.08.2020                   0.30           <NA>       1      1
#> 15:    A 03.08.2020                   0.30           <NA>       1      1
#> 16:    A 04.08.2020                   0.05           <NA>       1      1
#> 17:    A 05.08.2020                   0.00           <NA>       1      1
#> 18:    A 06.08.2020                   0.00           <NA>       1      1
#> 19:    A 07.08.2020                   0.01     05.08.2020       2      1
#> 20:    A 08.08.2020                   0.10           <NA>       2     NA
#> 21:    A 09.08.2020                   0.20           <NA>       2     NA
#>     Unit       Date Prcent_daily.mortality Date.treatment postgrp pregrp
#calculation
odt[!is.na(pregrp),akkum.7dbty:=sum(tail(Prcent_daily.mortality[-.N],7)),by=.(Unit,pregrp)]
odt[postgrp!=0,days.post.treatment:= 0:(.N-1),by=.(Unit,postgrp)]

#result
odt[,c("postgrp","pregrp"):=NULL][]
#>     Unit       Date Prcent_daily.mortality Date.treatment akkum.7dbty
#>  1:    A 20.07.2020                   0.20           <NA>          NA
#>  2:    A 21.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>        1.35
#>  3:    A 22.07.2020                   0.40           <NA>        1.35
#>  4:    A 23.07.2020                   0.30           <NA>        1.35
#>  5:    A 24.07.2020                   0.60           <NA>        1.35
#>  6:    A 25.07.2020                   0.05           <NA>        1.35
#>  7:    A 26.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>        1.35
#>  8:    A 27.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>        1.35
#>  9:    A 28.07.2020                   0.01     28.07.2020        1.35
#> 10:    A 29.07.2020                   0.10           <NA>          NA
#> 11:    A 30.07.2020                   0.20           <NA>          NA
#> 12:    A 31.07.2020                   0.00           <NA>        0.85
#> 13:    A 01.08.2020                   0.20           <NA>        0.85
#> 14:    A 02.08.2020                   0.30           <NA>        0.85
#> 15:    A 03.08.2020                   0.30           <NA>        0.85
#> 16:    A 04.08.2020                   0.05           <NA>        0.85
#> 17:    A 05.08.2020                   0.00           <NA>        0.85
#> 18:    A 06.08.2020                   0.00           <NA>        0.85
#> 19:    A 07.08.2020                   0.01     05.08.2020        0.85
#> 20:    A 08.08.2020                   0.10           <NA>          NA
#> 21:    A 09.08.2020                   0.20           <NA>          NA
#>     Unit       Date Prcent_daily.mortality Date.treatment akkum.7dbty
#>     days.post.treatment
#>  1:                  NA
#>  2:                  NA
#>  3:                  NA
#>  4:                  NA
#>  5:                  NA
#>  6:                  NA
#>  7:                  NA
#>  8:                  NA
#>  9:                   0
#> 10:                   1
#> 11:                   2
#> 12:                   3
#> 13:                   4
#> 14:                   5
#> 15:                   6
#> 16:                   7
#> 17:                   8
#> 18:                   9
#> 19:                   0
#> 20:                   1
#> 21:                   2
#>     days.post.treatment
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>